# Add text formatation to text close checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

i have this little issue in my wordpress website. I want to add a font-weight to the text "Spain" when the checkbox near it is checked. I tried diferent codes in jquery, one os those using WrapInner() but without success

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="pais_produtores-spain">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pais_produtores-spain" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-pais_produtores[]" value="spain" checked="checked">
        Spain
    </label>
</div>
```

Whats the best solution for this little issue?

Answer (score 1):

with the jquery `.is(':checked')` you can see if a checkbox is checked and then apply styling with jquery's `.css()` function

```js
$( "#pais_produtores-spain" ).on( "click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log('now its checked');
    $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'bolder');
  }else{
    console.log('not checked anymore');
    $(this).parent().css('font-weight', 'normal');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="pais_produtores-spain">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pais_produtores-spain" class="js-wpv-filter-trigger" name="wpv-pais_produtores[]" value="spain" checked="checked">
        Spain
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Its an amazing solution, and thanks for the help since now, but after i "check" the input box, the filter updates and the bold goes away, i traid to use a timeout to wait for the end of the filter "reload" but without success. Any tip?

Comment: Not sure, but think its an ajax request that load all the filters, after the checkbox is selected

Comment: would you mind sharing the website link? usually we dont ask for those and rather see code to help you. but in this case i want to see what is happening to see if i can help you out here